# How long does Expo's SecureStore last?

Tags: react-native, expo

If I use SecureStore to save a list of messages that will never be backed up, what is the risk that they will get deleted/lost? I'm surprised this was never asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secure store stores data keychain services on ios and sharedpreferences on android so there is no time limit. If you remove app, os will delete stored datas. 
[But there is size limit.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/)